# Correct usage of scalaz Future for async execution

Tags: scala, asynchronous, future, scalaz, spray

I guess i don't fully understand how scalaz Futures works. I'm trying to port one project from scala futures to scalaz implementation, but the problem is that performance with scalaz Future is lower. The simplest example is loading a profile on authentication request with Spray.

The function itself:

```
def loadProfile[A: CollectionProvider: JsonFormat](id: String) = future {
  remote.findOne[A]("id" :> id) match {
    case Some(profile) ⇒ \/-(profile)
    case None          ⇒ -\/(ProfileNotFoundRejection(id))
  }
}
```

scalaz version differs just in one symbol, i'm calling `Future.apply` from `scalaz.concurrent`.
And now the Spray route which loads some html page:

```
get {
  path("profile" / "id" ~ Segment) { id ⇒
    onSuccess(loadProfile[User](id)) {
      case \/-(profile) ⇒ complete(html.page(profile))
      case -\/(pnfr)    ⇒ reject(pnfr)
    }
  }
}
```

As with `loadProfile`, scalaz version differs just in on method call:

```
get {
  path("profile" / "id" ~ Segment) { id ⇒
    ctx => loadProfile[User](id).runAsync {
      case \/-(profile) ⇒ ctx.complete(html.page(profile))
      case -\/(pnfr)    ⇒ ctx.reject(pnfr)
    }
  }
}
```

But the request with scala Future version completes in (around) **143ms**, while scalaz version completes in **260ms**. So i'm not much concerned about this particular request, but about asynchronous execution and scalability of service in general, as i understand in scalaz Future i have to fork execution to a separate thread manually, so it executes sequentially? Are there any good intro/tutorial into scalaz Future usage?

Comment: Sorry, pressed return too soon. Perhaps it is related to the underlying ExecutorService used to perform the computation? Scalaz's `Future.apply` takes an ExecutorService as an implicit parameter. By default it uses `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool(...)` using the number of processors available on your machine. `Future`s created within Spray routes will by default use the Akka dispatcher, which is a Fork-Join pool.

Answer (score 1):

scala and scalaz futures are **very** different:

### Scala

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

// creating two slow futures:
val f: Future[Unit] = Future { println("f " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); Thread.sleep(10000);  }
val g: Future[Unit] = Future { println("g " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); Thread.sleep(10000);  }

// and after moment asking for success
f onSuccess { case _ => println("f s1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
g onSuccess { case _ => println("g s1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
f onSuccess { case _ => println("f s2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
g onSuccess { case _ => println("g s2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
```

We get an output, immediately after creating `f` and `g`

```
f ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
g ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
```

And rest output after ~10 seconds

```
f s1 ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
g s1 ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
f s2 ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
g s2 ForkJoinPool-1-worker-5
```

### Scalaz

```
import scalaz.concurrent._ // z!
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._

// creating two slow futures:
val f: Future[Unit] = Future { println("f " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); Thread.sleep(10000);  }
val g: Future[Unit] = Future { println("g " + Thread.currentThread().getName()); Thread.sleep(10000);  }
```

After creating `f` and `g`, nothing happens. We have:

```
f: scalaz.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Async(<function1>)
g: scalaz.concurrent.Future[Unit] = Async(<function1>)
```

But after run them we see the difference:

```
f runAsync { _ => println("f s1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
g runAsync { _ => println("g s1 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
f runAsync { _ => println("f s2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
g runAsync { _ => println("g s2 " + Thread.currentThread().getName()) }
```

We get result:

```
f pool-4-thread-2
g pool-4-thread-1
f pool-4-thread-4
g pool-4-thread-3

f s2 pool-4-thread-4
g s2 pool-4-thread-3
g s1 pool-4-thread-1
f s1 pool-4-thread-2
```

There are two points worth mentioning:

- the Futures `f` and `g` are executed again. There is no value memoisation.
- The `runAsync` callback is executed in the same thread as the first computation. This because we don't **explicitly** fork.

---

It's hard to say why they perform differently in your example. The most time should be spend in `remove.findOne` anyway. You want to use `scala.concurrent.blocking` around blocking calls to help `ExecutorService` not to run into thread starvation (in both cases).